# UITableViewCell not respond

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have UITableView in class A, and custom view in class B. What i want is - add custom view from class B to view of class A, then remove that view and show table.

I did add view and logic to remove that view, but for some reason, my tableView cells are not responding to touching.

Here is how i create and add view (class B):

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andRemoveTableView:(UITableView*)tableView{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    NSLog(@"Calld");
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self addLabel];

     tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    return self;
}
```

Now implementation of class A:

```
@implementation MainTableViewController{

    InitialView *initView;
    BOOL isInitialViewTapped;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{

  //  InitialView *initView = [[InitialView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

//    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];


    initView = [[InitialView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds] andRemoveTableView:self.tableView];

    [self.view addSubview:initView];
   // [initView removeFromSuperview];

     //Notification Center

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(recieveTap:)
                                                 name:@"Tap"
                                               object:nil ];
    [self isViewTapped];

}

-(void)isViewTapped{


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

-(void)viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Tap" object:self];
    isInitialViewTapped = YES;
}

#pragma mark - table view delegate

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    //Fill data
    InitialData *data = [InitialData new];
    data.isFirstCall = YES;

    //Show cell

    myCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.taskText.text = [data.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.timeStartedText.text = [self dateStr];


    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return 3;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"SELECT");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push" sender:self];

}



#pragma mark - Notification Center

-(void)recieveTap:(NSNotification*)notification{

    if (!isInitialViewTapped){
    [initView  removeFromSuperview];

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"Tap"])

    }   else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward. But when i tap screen and make my custom view dismiss, when i click on cell segue not work. Actually, method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"SELECT");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push" sender:self];

}
```

not even print NSLog. How to fix that?

Comment: After the custom view disappeared, is `viewTapped:` still invoked? If so, try to remove the `tap gesture recognizer` when the custom view disappears and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewCell conflicts with UITapGestureRecognizer .

You can remove the gesture when -(void)viewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer is called.

If you want to keep the gesture, you should set the delegate of gesture.

```
-(void)isViewTapped{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(viewTapped:)];
    tap.delegate = self; // add this line
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    // TableViewCell, do not handle it
    if ([NSStringFromClass([touch.view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellContentView"]) {
        return NO;
    }
    return  YES;
}
```